# Trying to create a form that would give a print window containg form data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

As my title suggests, I'm trying to create a form that would take some user input like Name, Age, Gender, Hobbies, Contact details & Photo etc. (basically I'm thinking of making a simple local html based application that would create **RESUME**), and after taking user input, supposedly after clicking on the submit button it should create a new print window where every entered data should be arranged in a resume like format including photo.

This is what I'm trying for my input page...(ps: it's incomplete!!! most of my script part is just Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Resume maker</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="BMain" class="body">
          <h1>Please enter your resume data!</h1>
            <form action="#">
              <p>Name</p>
                <input type"text" id="name" name="name">
              <p>Mother's name</p>
                <input type"text" id="mName" name="mName">
              <p>Father's name</p>
                <input type"text" id="fName" name="fName">
              <p>Gender</p>
                <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
                  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
                  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
              <div class="container" id"dobPick">
              <p>Date of Birth</p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
               <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
              $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'L'
                });
            });
               </script>
              </div>
             </div>
              <label for="myfile">Upload your photo:</label>
              <input type="file" id="myPic" name="myPic"><br><br>
              <input type="submit">
              </form>
```

After clicking on the submit button I'm expecting a print window with predefined background image like some vector art or some stamp like image or some pattern, well that's post work.

This is how my print window should be looking...
[Print window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgM22.png)

Any help on this mates..... at this stage scripts looks too messy to me. I'm excited to try this on my browser.

My question is how can I make it happen or rather I say what should I do or add into my input page to get the desired output I'm expecting? My above code was just a conceptual example.

Comment: And your question is...? You haven't stated a concrete problem with your code. Do you get errors or just unexpected results? Be sure to read on [how to properly ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @El_Vanja Question added!

Comment: "Make it happen" makes for a very vague specification. Have you written any PHP code at all? Do you have any specific problems implementing this or are you just looking for a tutorial? Because if you're looking for the latter, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @El_Vanja You're not completely wrong, yes I've been looking for tutorials.

Comment: @El_Vanja I do have some html and javascript knowledge but I'm not sure how can I implement it! And I thought some of you might have done that...

Comment: @RunnyRat you would submit the data to a `php` file via `POST` and in the php file you would design  the print window(as you showed in the image) and also in that file you could data the posted data using `$_POST[FieldName]`. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9aePaXve6s) for a tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a second `div` element to the page outside of your form. Once the form is validated and submitted, it can be hidden and the second `div` can be populated with that information. You can then use CSS media queries (there are print-specific queries) and trigger the `print()` method in Javascript. You would need to include the following in your html file:

`<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "print" href = "mystyle.css">`

Then, if your markup were to look like this:

```
<div id="resumeform">
  <input id="name" type="text" />
  <input id="age" type="text" />
  <input id="address" type="text" />
  <input id="height" type="text" />
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit Info"/>
</div>
<div id="result">
  <span id="r_name"></span>
  <span id="r_age"></span>
  <span id="r_address"></span>
  <span id="r_height"></span>
</div>
```

Your JS could look like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
btn.addEventListener("click", btnHandler);

function btnHandler(el){
  var resumeform = document.getElementById("resumeform");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var address = document.getElementById("address");
  var height = document.getElementById("height");

  var r_name = document.getElementById("r_name");
  var r_age = document.getElementById("r_age");
  var r_address = document.getElementById("r_address");
  var r_height = document.getElementById("r_height");

  r_name.innerHTML = name.value;
  r_age.innerHTML = age.value;
  r_address.innerHTML = address.value;
  r_height.innerHTML = height.value;

  resumeform.style.display = "none";
  result.style.display = "block";
  window.print();
}
```

And your CSS could look like this:

```
#resumeform {
  display: block;
}
#result {
  display: none;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media print {
  span {
      /* Your CSS rules would go here */
  }
}
```

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9apfwjxz/